# How to set the Start Option for Audio in Powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint-2016

Using Powerpoint 2016 with Windows 10, I have selected an audio object. The Audio tools appear and under Playback tab and under Audio Options, I wish to set the Start option using VBA, as highlighted in yellow. I can set the other options such as Hide During Show, Rewind, Loop until Stopped by setting the appropriate PlaySettings Object property.
The 2 other options are "In click sequence" and "When Clicked On"

Unless I set Start to Automatically, when I move to the next slide, I sometimes have to perform another click to start the audio.

Really appeciate help and many thanks[image: PPT Start Option]

Comment: [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_other-mso_2010/using-vba-to-insert-and-automatically-play-audio/a56ac636-2a83-4c37-88d1-068ef01b52b9) looks good.

Comment: Thanks that has helped a lot.